# Working with smooth functions defined on a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am having trouble working with smooth functions defined on a manifold. Is the following line of reasoning valid or not?

Let $f$ be a smooth function defined on a manifold $M$ with a local maximum at point $p$. Let $F$ be a smooth function defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ which agrees with $f$ on $M\cap U$, the restriction of the set $U$ to the manifold.

Suppose I want to prove something like $df_p = 0$. Can I simply state that $df_p = dF_p$ which must be zero because $F$ also has a local maximum at $p$?

My problem is that I am not sure that $F$ is guaranteed to exist and whether or not I can use the normal rules of calculus with $F$. If my reasoning is wrong, should I just attack this problem via coordinate charts?

Comment: what does $M \cap U$ means ? (I would assume $M$ is the manifold but then $M \cap U$ is just $U$).

Comment: $U$ is a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is not necessarily contained in the manifold. I will re-word that part.

Comment: Are you thinking of $M$ as a submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, thank you.

Comment: Then why must $F$ have a local maximum at $p$? Consider $M = \{0\}\times\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $F(x,y) = - x^2 + y^2$, and $p = (0,0)$.

Comment: In general, it is easier to work intrinsically by using coordinate charts. There are far fewer things that can go wrong with usual rules of calculus when you work intrinsically, compared to when you work extrinsically and have to worry about extensions of functions to the ambient space.

Comment: @WillieWong, Is there any value in pursuing the idea when we require $U\cap M$ to be an open neighborhood around $p$ on the manifold? But I will most likely stick to coordinate charts for this problem, thank you.

Comment: If $M$ is a submanifold, then the induced (subspace) topology on $M$ is precisely such that for any $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $U\cap M$ is open in $M$. So the condition introduced in your last comment is always true, and not a restriction in anyway.

Comment: @WillieWong I was thinking about this again and I do not understand how the function $F(x,y)$ agrees on a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ on the manifold because it only shares a point of the manifold. Even in the induced topology, a neighborhood would require more points. I can't find an open set such that $U\cap M = (0,0)$.

Comment: huh? Are you talking about my example? $M$ is the $y$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Pick any open neighbourhood in the $y$-axis of the origin, you must be able (in the sense that you, as a student, should have already acquired this skill) to find an open set in the plane such that its intersection with the $y$-axis is the neighbourhood you started with.

Comment: Right, but I'm saying we don't have an open neighborhood in $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi:W\to M\cap U$ be a parametrization of $M$ near $p$, $W$ open in $\mathbb R^d$, $p=\varphi(a)$. Then $f\circ\varphi:W\to\mathbb R$ has a local maximum at $a$ and $d_a(f\circ\varphi)\equiv0$ (critical point). Now we translate this to $M$. The tangent space of $M$ at $p$ is $T_pM=\text{Im}(d_a\varphi)$. Since $f|M\cap U=F|M\cap U$ we have:
$$
0\equiv d_a(f\circ\varphi)=d_a(F\circ\varphi)=d_pF\circ d_a\varphi,
$$
which exactly means that $d_pF$ vanishes on the image of $d_a\varphi$, which is precisely $T_pM$. Hence:
$$
d_pf=d_pF|T_pM=0.
$$
This completes the argument. The condition $d_pF|T_pM\equiv0$ is just the famous Lagrange multipliers criterion for conditioned critical points. Note that $F$ needn't have a local maximum at $p$.

Summing up, $F$ does exists for $U$ small enough and the usual calculus rules work, *but restricted to tangent spaces*.